# batch script to find drive letter of a mounted device

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script to locate a particular mounted device. I'm in windows 7.

I know that the device will have the folder drive:\custom so I'm wanting to look at all possabilities to find a device with this path

Here is what i have so far

```
    @echo off
   setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion


for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d:\custom (
     ECHO Device Found : %%d
  )
)
```

This doesnt work though, it thinks it exists for every drive letter.. so i see 'Device Found' for every single drive letter.  Why is that? Am I going about this wrong? How can I locate the drive letter that has a folder 'custom' on the root directory?

thanks,
Stephanie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\` at the end of the path:

```
IF EXIST %%d:\custom\ (...)
```

Comment: this works .. kinda.. now it only falls into the if statemet if the file exists but everytime it does I get the popup error 'There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \device\harddisk1\dr115'

Comment: @Without Me It Just Aweso: Interesting... Obviously, the message has something to do with a removable disk drive. However I don't get any such message in XP when I run your sample script with my modification. Don't know why.

Comment: yea.. i cant figure it out. i tried changed the filepath its looking for to my C:\users just to see if it was a problem with my external device but I got the same error. I have no idea what its complaining about. On the error if i hit 'Continue' it works fine.. annoying that there is a popup everytime i run the script though

Comment: @Without Me It Just Aweso: Have you included `a` and/or `b` in the 'drive' list by any chance?

Comment: no I didnt. im having a really hard time tracking down the error. there are lots of things about it online but no good solutions..

Comment: On win7 x64 Didnt work: it says  
'Device Found: C: The system cannot find the device specified.'

Answer (score 3):

Use `fsutil fsinfo drives` inside the `for` statement instead of a static list of drive letters.

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
  :: work with %%j here
)
```

However, if a drive letter is given to a device with no media, it *may* still give an error. Either way, a check such as:

```
if not exist O:\ @echo test
```

worked perfectly fine for me (with and without `not`). The drive does not exist on my system, so no output was given when the `not` got removed.

Comment: This doesnt seem to do anything when I run it. Can you tell me what the '/f "toekns=1,*' does?

Comment: @Without Me It Just Aweso: the `/f` in conjunction with the single quotes executes the command in the single quotes adn tokenizes these. `"tokens=1,*"` tells it to grab the output of the command in the variables `%%i` (first token) and `%%j` (rest). And I tried it, it works. It wouldn't work on the command line because of the double `%%` (which is the syntax inside script files only). Remove one `%` and it should work on the command line as well. Obviously you would have to do something with the variable that receives the drive letters (`%%j`), e.g. pass them to whatever you did originally.

Answer (score 1):

A bit complicated, but this is the only solution to avoid blocking errors on Win7:

```dos
for /f "tokens=3" %%d in ('echo LIST Volume ^| DISKPART ^| findstr "Healthy Unusable"') do (
  if exist %%d:\custom echo Device found
)
```

Another method i've found is using the `vol` command + checking `ERRORLEVEL` (if == 1 the drive is not mounted):

```dos
for /f "tokens=3" %%d in ('echo LIST Volume ^| DISKPART ^| findstr "Healthy Unusable"') do (
   vol %%d:
   if !ERRORLEVEL!==0 if exist %%d:\custom echo Device found
)
```

NOTE: on WinXP `DISKPART` won't see removable drives...

Comment: didn't work on win7 x64 - it had to get User permission to run DISKPART (permissions popup) and then it was in a different window.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
:CICLO
CLS&ECHO.&ECHO  VER ESTADO UNIDADES CON WMIC
SET "DVF="

FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%A IN ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, description ^| FIND ":"') DO (

   VOL %%A >nul 2>&1 && (
      CALL SET "DVF=%%DVF%% %%A"& ECHO   %%A ^| ON.  %%B) || (
      ECHO   %%A ^| OFF. %%B
   )
)   
ECHO  DEVICEFOUND: %DVF%
TIMEOUT /T 5 >NUL
GOTO:CICLO
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but my English is... nothing.
There really is little to explain. We use "wmic LogicalDisk get caption, description" to extract the drivers (%% A) or the drivers and type (%% B). Vol is used to deduce whether the driver is ready and its output is modified at will. The '^ | FIND "" loop for formatting reasons is because otherwise we get carriage returns or whatnot wmic. However using '^ | findstr /i "X"', where X is local disk, hard disk, or CD-ROM, etc, can discriminate the type of driver you need. The loop is only for dynamically demonstrate its operation. :). A greeting.

Comment: You need to put that explanation *in the answer*.

Answer (score -2):

This works for a hard disk and a pendrive:

```
@echo off
for  %%? in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
        dir %%?:\ > nul 2>nul
        if exist %%?:\custom echo Device found(s): %%?:\ 
)
```

P.S.: Run WinXP