# batch script to list local hard drives and then do a dir command on each drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried to make a script following this topic

[batch script to find drive letter of a mounted device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709189/batch-script-to-find-drive-letter-of-a-mounted-device)

but there is no real success.

This is the script:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%i in (`fsutil fsinfo drives`) do (
    if exist %%j dir /S /D "%%j*hurrdurr.txt" >> fud_india.com_%computername%.txt
)
pause
```

Problem is i get the result, but only for 1 drive letter...

Anyone maybe can help here?

Comment: Is it a requirement that this script is implemented in batch? Things would be much easier if you could use [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx). See e.g. [Get-PSDrive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849796.aspx).

Comment: We stick to batch because we are not familiar with powershell yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >"fud_india.com_%computername%.txt" 2>nul (
        for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
            for %%c in (%%b) do vol %%~dc && dir /s /d "%%~dc\hurrdurr.txt"
        )
    )
```

The `for /f` just processes lines, in this case the output of the `fsutil` command, and is able to split those lines in tokens using the indicated set of delimiters. As the `fsutil` returns all the drives in one line, something like

```
Drives: C:\ D:\ E:\
```

and without knowing how many drives can be in the line, we can not (more or less) indicate how many tokens we want. So, we need to get the line, separate the header, grab the list and iterate over the elements in the list (the drives)

The first step is to separate the header from the list of drives. This is directly done in the `for /f %%a` via the `tokens` and `delims` clauses. We will use the colon as a delimiter to split the line in tokens.

We are requesting two tokens: ther first token (`%%a`) will store the text up to the first delimiter (the header) and the second token (`%%b`) will store the rest of the line (this is what the `*` means in the tokens clause)

With the list of drives stored in `%%b` we need a way to iterate over it.  This is the reason for `for %%c in (%%b) ...`. When `%%b` is expanded, the resulting command will be

```
for %%c in (C:\ D:\ E:\) do ...
```

For each element in the list a `vol` command is used to determine if the drive is available and if no errorlevel is set then the `dir` command is executed.

As the `vol` command only accepts a drive reference, without path, we need to remove the ending backslash from the elements in the list, so instead of directly using `%%c`, we use `%%~dc`, that is, the drive of the element being referenced in `%%c`.

The full `for` loop is enclosed in parenthesis and redirected so the output file only needs to be opened/closed once.

Comment: Your script works. Could you explain please how that for %%c in (%%b) .. line of code works?

Comment: @bapa, answer updated to include more details of how it works.

Comment: Hm... after i let this script do its job among domain computers, on some i get the error "Windows - No Disk" and people cannot login. :( Maybe its problem with fsutil and something does not initialize as fast as it should?

Comment: @bapa, as far as i know the posted code does does not include anything to change but `"fud_india.com_%computername%.txt"` and *maybe* temporary files or swap file if the OS decide to use them. Everything in the code is synchonous. I don't see a initialization problem. Maybe the script execution is the trigger, but the problem is in another place.

Comment: Could some time delay help with this? Maybe some part of windows does not initialize on time and generates this problem? I wanted to put this .txt file on a networked location - maybe network does not initialize fast enough at computer logon, and script already starts, but cannot reach networked location??

Comment: @bapa, it will depend on when or how you start the script. But you can always retrieve the information to a local file and then/later move the retrieved information to the network.

Comment: I put the script at computer logon. I dont know if network location does hog the machine, its only a wild guess.

Comment: This is the problem i encounter on some computers:

http://bp3.blogger.com/_whLomW7o5fc/Ry5LIdeyBEI/AAAAAAAAAoQ/pnEQ32GBZdk/s400/error.jpg

Comment: I think it is a problem with floppy drives..... any script modification in which it ignores floppy drives??

Comment: @bapa, i have installed a USB floppy (sorry, i don't have access to a internal one) and there is no problem running the code, with or without media in drive. I've been looking at MS and it seems the problem raises because drive letters get somehow changed, specially drive `C`. And the recomended solution is to use the `Disk Management` to reassign the drive letters. If this is of no help, i think it should be better to ask at SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: I tried on virtual and normal machine. When i remove floppy drive, script works, so its definitely floppy related :)

Comment: How to modify this script so it doesnt count floppy in?

Comment: I suspect you could use `fsutil fsinfo drivetype` to weed out drives that return `Removable Drive, for example floppy`

Answer (score 1):

your `%%j`contains `C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:` (for me), this makes your `if`:

```
if exist C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\ dir ...
```

obviously wrong syntax.

I suggest another method (wmic):

```
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
  dir /s /d %%i\*hurrdurr.txt" >>fud_india.com_%computername%.txt 2>nul
)
```

By getting rid of the `if exist`, you avoid the GUI-Box "no media"; `>nul` just sends the `dir`-error to nirvana.

Comment: Hm...... i tried this script, but it did not work. All i get is batch output:

Volume in drive C is System
Volume Serial Number is xyz
File Not Found
Volume in drive E is Data
Volume Serial Number is E08A-0F2D
File Not Found
Volume in drive C is System
Volume Serial Number is xyz
File Not Found

Comment: just tried again (with another filename, that exists on my drives): works fine here.

Comment: Is that script you wrote the whole script? Because i tried it alone, without any pre-script stuff i wrote up there and it didnt work? P.S. i'm trying it on winxp

Comment: should also work in XP. Does `wmic logicaldisk get caption` alone work?