# How to find drive and path of program installed using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have to dynamically find out the drive and path where a particular folder is located

For E.g: D:\sahi_pro_runner

Here sahi_pro_runner is installed in D:. It can be any installed in any drive and with the help of a batch file, I need to get the absolute path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear.  Are you looking to find all instances of a certain **folder name** on all drives?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be really helpful if you could post the code of your attempt to solve this as it would offer us something to start on.

Comment: It depends. Does this program has an installer? Or is just unzipped somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. sahi_pro_runner is the folder where sahi tools are installed. This tools can be installed by a user on any drive but for me to push the script inside tools, I have to know the specific path. It is like unzipped somewhere

Comment: Surely once unzipped under the control of an end user, the holding directory can also be renamed too! My advice would be to check the location of one or multiple uniquely named tool(s)/file(s) inside that directory.

Comment: Try `help dir`. `fsutil fsinfo drives` will give you a drive list, but you'll have to parse that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch script to list local hard drives and then do a dir command on each drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484348/batch-script-to-list-local-hard-drives-and-then-do-a-dir-command-on-each-drive)